# Right side view of BST - Python

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I am trying to find the right side view of a BST. I am able to get a working solution but I noticed a perculiatity with using

for i in q:  vs for i in range(len(q))

To elaborate the below code works

```
 Definition for a binary tree node.
 class TreeNode:
     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
         self.val = val
         self.left = left
         self.right = right
class Solution:
def rightSideView(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> List[int]:
    if root == None:
        return []

    result = []
    
    q = []
    q.append(root)
    
    while len(q):
        
        for _ in range(len(q)):
            node = q.pop(0)
            if node.left != None:
                q.append(node.left)
                
            if node.right != None:
                q.append(node.right)
        result.append(node.val)
        
    return result
```

but then when I change the below

for _ in range(len(q)):

to

for _ in (q):

as shown below

```
    if root == None:
        return []

    result = []
    
    q = []
    q.append(root)
    
    while len(q):
        
        for _ in (q):
            node = q.pop(0)
            if node.left != None:
                q.append(node.left)
                
            if node.right != None:
                q.append(node.right)
        result.append(node.val)
        
    return result
```

I know longer get the right side view. Anyone have any idea why this is the case.

For example with the input

Input: root = [1,2,3,null,5,null,4]

I get the output using the range(len(q)) code
Output: [1,3,4]

but when I try using the range(q) code I get the output
Output: [2,5,4]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're modifying `q` while iterating over it by popping the first element off.  The iterator than gets the element from the next position in the the list, but all of the elements have shifted left by 1 position.

In the first example, using `range(len(q))`, the results work out because the iterator was defined based on the length of `q` at the start of the loop, so if `q` had 4 elements, it will always loop for 4 iterations. `_ in (0, 1, 2, 3)`

In the second example, each time you call `q.pop(0)`, it shifts the elements of the list left by one position, which causes it to skip every other element.

Example:

```
a = [ x for x in range(10)]
for val in a:
    print(val, a.pop(0))

# OUTPUT
 0 0
 2 1
 4 2
 6 3
 8 4
```

Note how val was only getting the even values, because the iterator created by the for loop is getting the next position in the list (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, etc), while the list itself is being shifted left on every iteration. This also means it only gets 5 values instead of 10 before hitting the StopIteration exception that ends the loop.

Comment: Got it. That makes perfect sense. Based on that logic I would assume they append has no affect then? Because you are modifying the end of the list not what is being iterated through?

Comment: The values are still appended, and they may unintenionally be picked up in that pass of the for loop as well.

Comment: For example, if the list starts with just root, and it has left and right nodes, the for loop starts at index 0. you then pop(0) and add 2 elements, node.left (at index 0) and node.right (at index 1).  The next iteration goes to index 1 and gets node.right. After that it tries to get q[2], etc.